# Haptic vibration when Siri is ready to listen - Worked in iOS 12 but gone in iOS 13?

Tags: iphone, siri, ios, haptic-feedback

With iOS 11 & 12 on my iPhone 5s, when I held down the home-button to activate Siri, I would get a haptic vibration when Siri was ready to listen for a command.

Now, new phone (iPhone SE), and new iOS, iOS 13.1.2: No haptic feedback after pressing the home-button for Siri. When Siri responds to a command, *then* I get a haptic shake.

➥ Is this the new normal? Is there a way to activate the haptic-shake-when-listening feature?

The haptic feedback was quite useful when using the iPhone without looking.

I am not using the "Hey Siri" always-listening feature, nor do I want to.

Comment: What's the "belly button"?

Comment: Possibly the "home button" (the one above the charge/accessory port)